# Binary search tree not inserting/printing actual largest value unless it is implemented as root

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm learning binary search trees right now and made one myself. The problem with my tree is that the `traverse()` method doesn't print the largest value ('15' in the code pasted below), unless it is the first value to be inserted.

I've also tried `getMaxValue()` function and it also doesn't return the expected value, instead gives the second largest value.
This lead to me thinking that the problem must be in `insert()` function somewhere, but it's been an hour and i can't find a fix or what I did wrong.

```
class Node(object):

  def __init__(self,data):
    self.data = data
    self.leftChild = None
    self.rightChild = None


class BinarySearchTree(object):

  def __init__(self):
    self.root = None

  #Parent function of insert
  def insert(self,data):
    if not self.root:
      self.root = Node(data)
    else:
      self.insertNode(data,self.root)

  # O(log n) if the tree is balanced!!!! 
  # thats why AVL and RBT are needed!
  #Child function of insert
  def insertNode(self,data,node):

    if data < node.data:
      # check if there is already a left child, if it is not null then we call insertNode recursively and insert a node as its child
      if node.leftChild:
        self.insertNode(data,node.leftChild)
        # if there is no left child then we instantiate it, and make a left child, same stuff happening for right child 
      else:
        node.leftChild = Node(data)
    else:
      if node.rightChild:
        self.insertNode(data, node.rightChild)
      else:
        self.rightChild = Node(data)

#Parent function of getminvalue
  def getMinValue(self):
    if self.root:
      return self.getMin(self.root)

#Child function of getminvalue
  def getMin(self,node):
  #if there is a left child
    if node.leftChild:
      #go to left child recursively
      return self.getMin(node.leftChild)

    return node.data

#Parent function of getMaxValue  
  def getMaxValue(self):
    if self.root:
      return self.getMax(self.root)

#Child function of getmaxValue
  def getMax(self, node):

    if node.rightChild:
      return self.getMax(node.rightChild)

    return node.data 

#Parent function of traverse
  def traverse(self):
    if self.root:
      self.traverseInOrder(self.root)

#Child function of traverseinOrder  
  def traverseInOrder(self,node):

    if node.leftChild:
      self.traverseInOrder(node.leftChild)

    print("%s " % node.data)

    if node.rightChild:
      self.traverseInOrder(node.rightChild)


#Inputs
bst = BinarySearchTree()

bst.insert(10)
bst.insert(15)
bst.insert(5)
bst.insert(4)
bst.insert(3)

print(bst.traverse())
```

The expected result is

```
3
4
5
10
15
```

but I'm getting

```
3
4
5
10 
None
```

Comment: The reason it prints `None` at the end is likely because `traverse()` doesn't return anything. Yet to figure out why `15` isn't printed though.

Comment: The problem is with your right child insertion. It should be `node.rightChild = Node(data)`, not `self.rightChild`. The rest is fine, just don't print `traverse` and you won't get `None`. Also just mentioning that while your comment about AVL Trees is correct, your structure is a normal BST which isn't being balanced, so the complexity would be based on the height of the tree.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

fixed:

will soon edit with details

```py
class Node(object):

  def __init__(self,data):
    self.data = data
    self.leftChild = None
    self.rightChild = None


class BinarySearchTree(object):

  def __init__(self):
    self.root = None

  #Parent function of insert
  def insert(self,data):
    if not self.root:
      self.root = Node(data)
    else:
      self.insertNode(data,self.root)

  # O(log n) if the tree is balanced!!!!
  # thats why AVL and RBT are needed!
  #Child function of insert
  def insertNode(self,data,node):

    if data < node.data:
      # check if there is already a left child, if it is not null then we call insertNode recursively and insert a node as its child
      if node.leftChild:
        self.insertNode(data,node.leftChild)
        # if there is no left child then we instantiate it, and make a left child, same stuff happening for right child
      else:
        node.leftChild = Node(data)
    else:
      if node.rightChild:
        self.insertNode(data, node.rightChild)
      else:
        node.rightChild = Node(data)

#Parent function of getminvalue
  def getMinValue(self):
    if self.root:
      return self.getMin(self.root)

#Child function of getminvalue
  def getMin(self,node):
  #if there is a left child
    if node.leftChild:
      #go to left child recursively
      return self.getMin(node.leftChild)

    return node.data

#Parent function of getMaxValue
  def getMaxValue(self):
    if self.root:
      return self.getMax(self.root)

#Child function of getmaxValue
  def getMax(self, node):

    if node.rightChild:
      return self.getMax(node.rightChild)

    return node.data

#Parent function of traverse
  def traverse(self):
    if self.root:
      self.traverseInOrder(self.root)

#Child function of traverseinOrder
  def traverseInOrder(self,node):

    if node.leftChild:
      self.traverseInOrder(node.leftChild)

    print("%s " % node.data)

    if node.rightChild:
      self.traverseInOrder(node.rightChild)


#Inputs
bst = BinarySearchTree()

bst.insert(10)
bst.insert(15)
bst.insert(5)
bst.insert(4)
bst.insert(3)

bst.traverse()
```

I stepped through the code with a debugger (which I recommend you do, it is very helpful), and saw this:

[image: debugger]

as you can see, `node` with data `10` has no right child, whereas `self` has a `root` with data `10` and `rightChild` with data `15`.

that made me look at the line that insert a new right child, there you had mistakenly wrote: `self.rightChild = Node(data)` instead of `node.rightChild = Node(data)` (like you correctly do with the left child)